# playing a .mp3 file on my timer with javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, mp3

Complete JavaScript beginner here. I'm coding a timer that reset's its countdown whenever the mouse moves or a key on the keyboard is pressed. With a little luck I was able to get it to function, but I don't know how to get the audio to my alarm.mp3 file to play.

I know it's probably simple, but after almost a month of figuring this out I'm really getting burned out. Here's my JavaScript, any help is appreciated.

```
const fiveMinutes = 5
var start, diff, minutes,seconds;

var display;
var timerStarted = false
var resetCtr = 0;  
var debugMsg;
const debug = true;


function startTimer(duration) {
    
    start = Date.now()

    function timer() {
        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        
        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
};
    timer();
    setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

function btnStartTimer() {
    if (!timerStarted) {
        timerStarted = true;
        startTimer(fiveMinutes);
    }
}

function resetTimer(){
    if (timerStarted) {
        startTimer(fiveMinutes);
    }
}


window.onload = function () {
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code on Windows 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// You can create a sound source as follows:

const audio = new Audio("/path/to/you/alarm.mp3");

// And when you need to play a sound, all you have to do is call the following function:

audio.play();
```